# How to perform the test class coverage for "lastmodified" date in salesforce?

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, code-coverage

I am trying to test the class coverage for a system protected fields for test code coverage.

The salesforce provided solution [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro).

Not allowing me to set the dynamic date and I have the triggers as well because of that, even though I utilize `test.setStartDate()` the modified date is being effected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://sfdcvva.wordpress.com/2018/08/11/test-class-coverage-for-lastmodified-date/) is a helpful link which could be useful to you

The following code is for to Set system protected fields test code coverage,
as we know from here we can set created date field then what about the last modified date?

Here comes the answer:
The Use case is if we are using SOQL with filter conditions on last modified date like,

```
    SELECT Id,Name FROM Lead WHERE DAY_ONLY(lastmodifieddate)=today and 
    HOUR_IN_DAY(lastmodifieddate)>4 and HOUR_IN_DAY(lastmodifieddate)<15
```

we can see I am querying records which are modified today and time in between 4 to 15 (GMT hours) and am in need of the dynamic test data of today and in a specific time slot.
Then how to cover this, bam using round-trip serialization.

```
    Lead l= new Lead();
    l.lastName='test';
    l.Status='New';
    l.Company='test';
    Date myDate = Date.today();
     Time myTime = Time.newInstance(8, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.newInstanceGMT(myDate, myTime);
    l.CreatedDate=dt1;
    l.LastModifiedDate=dt1;
     //I am serializing the sobject to string.
     string leadJSON=JSON.serialize(l);
     //I am De-serializing the string back to sobject
     Lead ll = (Lead) JSON.deserialize(leadJSON, Lead.class );
     //In this way it will accept the dynamic dates we specify for system                               date fields.
    insert ll;
    //Remember this is for test class purpose only.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow VVA. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)